# What is the max network latency between synchronous-commit AlwaysOn Availability Groups

Tags: sql-server, availability-groups, data-synchronization, network, sap

Is there a maximum supported network latency (ms) between two synchronous AlwaysOn replica?
I need to give this information to network administrators for configuring the link between the two nodes of the cluster.
I know that syncronization between replicas is influenced by disk speed and other things: The picture in this [article](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/sql-server-support/troubleshooting-data-movement-latency-between-synchronous-commit/ba-p/319141#) explain the process involved.
The AlwaysOn instance will host the sap database (1 TB of data) and I estimate that the workload will be considerable with large transactions.

Comment: The best practice is 1ms latency.  As for the maximum tolerable, that depends entirely on how much performance you're willing to sacrifice for the benefit of synchronous replication.

Comment: @TonyHinkle is that documented somewhere, or personal experience?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no maximum for the supported latency for synchronous replicas.  You will sometimes opt for a higher-latency deployment in return for a [RPO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disaster_recovery#Recovery_Point_Objective)=0 for a broader range of failures.

The most common mission-critical configuration is to have a pair of synchronous replicas on separate racks in the same datacenter, and a third, asynchronous replica in a separate datacenter.

But guidance for your scenario should probably come from SAP, or from the Microsoft/SAP Engineering Alliance.  See eg https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/running-sap-applications-on-the/bg-p/SAPApplications/label-name/AlwaysOn